# Why is the name for God אֱלּוֹהִים (Elohim) plural?

Tags: hebrew, hebrew-bible, names-of-god, onomastics

If Old Testament Judaism was a monotheistic religion, and Yahweh wanted to distinguish the Hebrews from their neighboring countries' polytheistic religions, why is His name אֱלוֹהִים (Elohim) plural?

> בְּ·רֵאשִׁ֖ית»be·re·Shit»In the beginning בָּרָ֣א»ba·Ra»created אֱלֹהִ֑ים»E·lo·Him;»God אֵ֥ת»'et» הַ·שָּׁמַ֖יִם»hash·sha·Ma·yim»the heaven וְ·אֵ֥ת»ve·'Et» הָ·אָֽרֶץ׃»ha·'A·retz.»the earth `HiSB Gen 1:1`

> In the beginning, God created the heavens and the earth. `ESV Genesis 1:1`

אֱלוֹהִים (Elohim) is used "no less than 2,500 times" ([Pohle-Preuss vol. 1](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=3787) Part II, ch. 1, §1, §§1).

<sub>My question is more general than "[In Genesis 20:13, why is elohim with a plural verb translated God rather than gods?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/11417/8491)" or "[Why is Elohim translated as God rather than gods in Genesis 1:1?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/8331/8491)."</sub>

Comment: אֱלוֹהִים is not a name. יהוה (Yahweh) is.

Comment: @DerÜbermensch What is it, then?

Comment: אֱלוֹהִים is a common noun; it tells us what יהוה is. cf. [Jos. 22:34](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jos/22/34/t_conc_209034): “Yahweh is the god.”

Comment: @DerÜbermensch Yes, יַהְוֶה (Yahweh) is His proper name.

Comment: Actually "Why is Elohim translated as God rather than gods in Genesis 1:1?." answers this question quite well.

Comment: @MikeBorden The accepted answer there states facts but not reasons behind why Elohim is plural.