# You all are gods vs. You all are God?

Tags: hebrew, grammar, psalms

### Plural Usage

In the answer of [Why is elohim translated as God rather than gods?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8331/why-is-elohim-translated-as-god-rather-than-gods-in-genesis-11) the plural usage occurs because of the verb or adjective.

**Psalm 82:6 WLC**

> אֲ‍ֽנִי־אָ֭מַרְתִּי אֱלֹהִ֣ים אַתֶּ֑ם וּבְנֵ֖י עֶלְיֹ֣ון כֻּלְּכֶֽם׃

What makes Psalm 82:6 special that it should translate as gods rather than God?

> You are all gods
>
> You are all God

What are the supporting Hebrew language rules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Psalm 82:6, the phrase "You are gods" has the pronoun "you" namely, אַתֶּ֑ם (’at·tem) which is second person masculine plural.  Thus Elohim must be translated in the plural.

If the pronoun were singular, אַתָּ֖ה (’at·tāh), then the Elohim would be translated in the singular, "You are God", as in: 2 Sam 7:28, 1 Kings 18:36, 1 Chron 17:26, Ps 86:10, 90:2, etc.

Comment: Agreed and this is cross referenced with Jesus in John 10:34 in the Greek.

Comment: You might want to mention that these are the same אלהים mentioned earlier in the Psalm when it says בקרב אלהים ישפט.